# Cannot read property 'startFlow' of undefined in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, visual-workflow

I am looking to override a standard New page on a custom objects with a custom lightning component. However, as I am attempt to run the new button, I get this error.

[image]

The lightning component with the flow is referenced like this

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:actionOverride,lightning:availableForFlowScreens" access="global">   
 <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
 <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData"/>
</aura:component>
```

And the Controller like so

```
 ({
init : function (component) {
    var flow = component.find("flowData");
    flow.startFlow("New_Lead_Supervisor");
 }
})
```

Comment: Maybe don't do this on init (I know the example has that, but it could be wrong) - try starting the flow on value render

Comment: Also make sure you have the name exactly right. You could check the name of the flow (capitalisation etc in workbench)

Comment: Finally, check your api version is correct for this new flow component.

Comment: @Medhanie - I have also come across this issue. Were you able to get any resolution around this?